# MEAN Stack login/register in different page than main app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, jwt

Sorry for my bad English!
I build an app using `MEAN Stack` (MongoDB + Express.js + Angular.js + Node.js) and authentication using `passport.js` and `JWT` (`jsonwebtoken` and `express-jwt`).
*What i want to do?*
The login and registration routes render html, using nunjucks, and if it goes success we render index.html file, placing in public directory. 
P.S.: is this a correct method?
*What is my question?*
Can anyone tell me, the technology to do this?
My code (based on https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial):

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
if (!req.user)
  res.redirect('/about')
else
  res.render('index')
});

app.get('/login',function(req, res) {
  res.render('auth/login', {
    title: 'Login'
  });
});

app.post('/',  function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.body.login || !req.body.password) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Please fill out all fields' });
    }
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      if (user) { return res.json({ token: user.generateJWT()});
      /*generateJWT form user model code returns jwt.sign({}) using jsonwebtoken:
          var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
       */
      } else { return res.status(401).json(info);}
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

In this code we return generated token, if login is success. What should i do to render index.html and what could i do with generated token?
Sorry for this dummy questions, i'm still learning jwt. Thank's

Comment: This is server side node code correct?

Comment: Think it's correct, I just tried to run. Do you see any mistakes? Thank you for answer

Answer (score 0):

Node is a Server Side Language. Since you are using MEAN stack, generally,
you need to create APIs in node and pass datas to client side Angular.

So to answer your question- To render html, your function for login needs to return something to client, using callbacks, and Angular will render your html pages.

What you need to do with the generated token is that from next time any requests to server without the token will/should generate error.
Else anyone can call your node APIs and and desired results. This is extremely necessary atleast for GET methods.

Comment: Thank's. In angular i want to use ui-router to create routes. But my login page is look like [this](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/pages/examples/login.html), and index page is look like [this](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/pages/examples/blank.html). So I thought that I need to render login page in backend and basic logic (after login) in frontend, using angular. How usually do the login and registration templates like [AdminLte](https://almsaeedstudio.com/AdminLTE)?